# Recommendation for Efficient Lindblad Simulator Packages

Tags: simulation, resource-request, open-quantum-systems

Could anyone recommend some efficiently established packages to simulate Lindblad dynamics? I wrote some codes using numpy to solve the vectorized superoperator equation but it's rather slow.

---

Update: I've tried three methods so far:

1. Superoperator with NumPy
2. Numerical integrating ode with NumPy
3. Qutip (implemented with scipy ode)

Here are the results (time in s)
number of qubits:  2
Method 0: unitary dynamics for comparison:  0.046922922134399414
Method 1 numpy with vectorization:  0.0637671947479248
Method 2: numpy ode:  1.5916249752044678
Method 3: qutip:  0.4054644823074341

number of qubits:  3
Method 0: unitary dynamics for comparison:  0.026817798614501953
Method 1 numpy with vectorization:  0.278156042098999
Method 2: numpy ode:  2.077683925628662
Method 3: qutip:  0.5400867462158203

number of qubits:  4
Method 0: unitary dynamics for comparison:  0.02422299385070801
Method 1 numpy with vectorization:  4.19312310218811
Method 2: numpy ode:  3.125500202178955
Method 3: qutip:  0.7155057668685914

number of qubits:  5
Method 0: unitary dynamics for comparison:  0.03640482425689697
Method 1 numpy with vectorization:  81.54041790962219
Method 2: numpy ode:  10.018388986587524
Method 3: qutip:  2.1129989862442016

number of qubits:  6
Method 0: unitary dynamics for comparison:  0.09250009059906006
Method 3: qutip:  4.948623609542847

number of qubits:  7
Method 0: unitary dynamics for comparison:  1.1378232717514039

number of qubits:  8
Method 0: unitary dynamics for comparison:  1.9191678524017335

Comment: Maybe QuTip is what you need?

Comment: Do you need a gate level simulator or a simulator for an arbitrary Hamiltonian?

Comment: @JahanClaes Thanks! QuTip is faster than my own codes but I'm still seeking faster methods.

Comment: For faster methods you'll probably need to migrate from Python to something like C+, or Julia.

Comment: try QuantumOptics.jl: https://qojulia.org/